# Kendo Angular2 npm from build server?

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

I have a new Ng2 project that is using the Kendo Grid for Angular 2.  These npm packages live on a Telerik npm repo, and require a login.  Our TeamCity build systems are firewalled off from the interwebz and use an internal npm to proxy to the main npm servers.  What is the recommended method for using npm modules from the Telerik site (aka the @progress modules) in this situation?  Should I copy them locally and reference them locally for our builds?

Comment: Please check out the http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/installation/build-agents/ help topic

Answer (score 0):

If your private NPM server can cache the `@progress` modules, it may be easier for consumption and upgrades.

Otherwise, consider committing the node modules into source control.

The general advice for fetching packages from build servers is to use the credentials of a licensed developer, but this is not applicable for scenarios where the build system is isolated from the private NPM repository.

Comment: Unfortunately our company's internal NPM server is firewalled off from using anything other than the official NPM.  Additionally, the internal NPM server doesn't support that @progress/module naming style.  Our solution here, after a lot of heart burn, was to not use Kendo for Angular2.

Comment: Well, if you decide otherwise, you can try committing only the `node_modules/@progress` directory into source control, and updating the Kendo packages from developer machines, if they have access to the private NPM registry.